# Which is natural regarding the use of relative pronoun?

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

which is acceptable?

1. Few of us can become movie stars that we would like to be
2. Few of us can become movie stars who we would like to be
3. Few of us can become movie stars whom we would like to be

Help!

Answer (score 3):

In 1, 2 and 3, you need the definite article and the plural of the noun for that structure to work:

1'. Few of us can become **the** movie star**s** that we would like to be.

Only "that" can be used in this case, because "movie stars" (just like "the man" in 4) refers to **a kind** of individual rather than an actual person.

We can of course also omit "that":

1''. Few of us can become the movie stars we would like to be.

4'. He is not the man he used to be.